# RS485 vs RS232 similarity vs differences

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, rs232, rs485, serial-bus

I have used UART RS232 communication between MCUs extensively. Now I need to interface my STM32F407 MCU over RS485 bus with with devices. I have understood few things about RS485 but not-clear about some points. Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding:

1. From MCU firmware point of view both are same since we use same pins for RS232 or RS485.
2. The main difference is in their signal voltage levels and point-to-point (RS232) or multipoint (RS485).

Comment: Shared schemes are *drastically* different because software must know *when* to talk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly right. Certain configurations of half duplex, collision detecting RS485 require a driver enable signal and software changes to detect the collision which RS232 would never need. RS485 might also have addressing implemented in hardware or software which RS232 would never have.

But for point-to-point communications you can essentially use the same code for both RS232 and full duplex RS485.

Comment: RS232 is byte oriented, what about RS485.. is bit or byte oriented?

Comment: With RS-485 there is a little more flexibility since you can have multi-master and multi-drop, but it still all goes back to what the UART module in the MCU allows, and not the RS-485 itself. The UART might allow you to send 7, 8, or 9-bits in between every stop and start bit, where the extra bit could be either a parity bit or address-flag bit, and the payload might be 7 bits, or 8bits. 

You would have to read the manual for the RS-485 device you are interfacing with to see the details of it's protocol (which you would have to do anyways to find out what messages it sends and receives).

Comment: Remember that RS-232 can also be configured have a parity bit as a 9th bit. So it's not entirely accurate to say it's byte oriented. It comes down to the UART behind the RS-232 and RS-485 transceiver. RS-232 and RS-485 is just the physical, electrical layer. For example, the UART is what produces the start and stop bits. Many quad encoders exist that output their pulses over RS-485 just as a stream of pulses with no start or stop bits.

Comment: Full duplex RS485 is known as RS422, so there is really no such thing as "full-duplex RS485".

Answer (score 1):

RS232 uses non-balanced signals. RS485 has balanced signals which increases noise immunity radically.

You are right that several devices can use same RS485 wires. Of course only one of them can can transmit at a time, but all can transmit in turns. RS232 doesn't have that capability, each wire has one dedicated transmitter. RS485 needs some complex software to retain law and order if there's several possible transmitters on the same bus. That's a general networking problem and it has several common solutions.

RS232 defines how transferred bits and characters are presented (=timing) and handshaking for flow control, RS485 defines only bit voltage levels, one can use as complex timings as he wants.

ERRATA: Comments claim that the common asynchronous communication data format with start- and stopbits isn't a part of RS232 spec. User Sam Gibson has checked it from the current standard, so it's a fact and I was wrong.

Comment: RS485 doesn't define timings any more, or less than RS-232 does...the UART defines that,

Comment: RS232 has data format and handshaking definitions. Maybe timing is a bad term for it.

Comment: Handshaking or software flow control are the terms you're looking for. But those are still defined by the UART standard and have nothing to do with the RS485 or RS232 which are hardware standards. The same handshaking can be used for full duplex RS485.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't the standards because they are copyrighted and high cost commercial stuff. Do you think that handouts like this are crap https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/product-selector-card/rs232%20quick%20guide.pdf

Comment: You might be right due to the evolution of RS-232 and use of ubiquitous terminology . But it's probably best to think of RS-232 as a hardware and UART as software since it is often used with different electrical interfaces.

Comment: Nobody prevents connecting UART via other than RS232 signals. Musicians have their MIDI, for ex.  But have you some facts which tell that in some phase RS232 in his life hasn't commented at all such things as word lengths or start-, stop,- and parity bits?

Comment: @user287001 - Hi, Just FYI, I have a copy of RS-232-F (latest version - now called ANSI/TIA/EIA-232-F). It *really* doesn't specify the data format to be the start/data/stop (i.e. embedded clock) format we use with UARTs. In fact it can't say that, because RS-232 is also (now rarely!) used to transfer data between devices with *synchronous* data streams. The clocks necessary for that synchronous data are on pins 15, 17 (and occasionally 24) of the standard 25-pin connector. The data (still on pins 2 & 3) then has no start or stop bits. Yes, that means the link you found on analog.com (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) ... is wrong, because it assumes that RS-232 is used for async data, and so it shows that data format. Of course now, that is the most common usage, as we know. But that doesn't change the fact that sync data on RS-232 has been used (I did protocol decoding as part of troubleshooting such connections, a long time ago, so I know it's part of the RS-232 standard). It's just that *now* async is so common, that for many people (and in that analog.com document) RS-232 = UART format (i.e. start/data/stop) but *strictly* that's not true and RS-232 standard doesn't say that. Hope that helps!

Comment: @SamGibson Seemingly beliefs and common practices are poor replacements for knowledge. Thanks! I'll fix my writing soon.

Comment: @user287001 - Glad I could help :-) I suspect that sync data over RS-232 is now so rare, that many people haven't seen it. (I haven't used it for over 20 years, but some of the IBM equipment involved *might* still be in use somewhere...) That's what happens with a standard first defined in the 1960s, which was used for all sorts of devices that are now obsolete, but that standard is still being used! Fewer and fewer people are still alive, who worked on those obsolete devices, so that knowledge gets slowly lost...

Comment: That does raise the question about where the start-stop bits are defined though because I just knew that RS-232 only specified the hardware, but still have no idea where the logical layer is specified.